# Constructor with argument passed in the form of object, how to build constructor property?

Tags: javascript

I have an Object constructor and I know that one of the arguments will pass data in the form of an Object. Cannot figure out how to build the constructor in a way that accepts the data in the form of an Object.

I have the following Constructor and I can't figure out what should be the value to `this.dimension`

```
function Box (name, dimensions) { 
    this.name = name;
    this.dimensions = ???;
}
```

Dimensions argument will be passed in the form of an object:

```
{
    width: 20,
    height: 30,
}
```

Comment: `this.dimensions = dimensions` works fine. Then you can create an object of type `Box` using `new Box('mailbox', { width: 20, height: 30 })`

Answer (score 2):

`this.dimensions = dimensions` works perfectly, even when `dimensions` is an Object:

```js
function Box(name, dimensions) {
  this.name = name;
  this.dimensions = dimensions;
}

var dims = {
  width: 20,
  height: 30,
}

var box = new Box('foo', dims);
console.log(box);
```

Comment: thanks @GalAbra. I had tried this already, my code must be breaking somewhere else. Will keep investigating then

Answer (score 1):

Try the following snippet:

```js
function Box (name, dimensions) { 
    this.name = name;
    this.dimensions = dimensions;
}

var dims = { height: 80, width: 40 }
var smallBox = new Box('small', dims)
console.log(smallBox.dimensions)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
function Box(name, dimensions) {
  this.name = name;
  this.dimensions = dimensions;
}
```

But if its confusing you can also use:

```
function Box(_name, _dimensions) {
  this.name = _name;
  this.dimensions = _dimensions;
}
```